# Can't find saved file in data/data/package name

Tags: android, ddms

I'm saving a hello.txt file with strings inside. But I cant find it in DDMS>selecting my package name in devices>File Explorer>data>data>package name.

Even my package name is cut. 
My package name is bla.Test9 but it only shows bla. Also under data/data it shows a lot of con folder, jps, and bla folder. Tried to ipen bla folder but I can't find the hello.txt inside

```
public void save(View v) {

        TextView dat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView gdat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        EditText gname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);   

        String s1, s2, s3, s4;

        s1 = dat.getText().toString();
        s2 = gdat.getText().toString();
        s3 = name.getText().toString();
        s4 = gname.getText().toString();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            file = getFilesDir();
            fos = openFileOutput("hello.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(s1.getBytes());
            fos.write(s2.getBytes());
            fos.write(s3.getBytes());
            fos.write(s4.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

**EDIT:** I'm using an emulator not a device.

Comment: yes. because these directories are private to your application, adb cannot access them.

Comment: you need to have root privileges to view/edit data folder contents

Comment: @user755 - how can I do that?

Comment: rooting solution for different devices are available on XDA.

Comment: @user755 - I'm using emulator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

LOL. Solved it. I just extend the window of name column in file explorer. Now i know why the names are cut.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

try it code

1. add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

1. in your code snippet

   fos.write(s4.getBytes());

   **fos.flush();**

Comment: On my friend's computer, I can view the hello.txt with my code. I don't think adding those line will do. There must be some problem..